# Store math operator in variable

Tags: c#, linq, mvvm, collectionview

I am creating an application in C# MVVM. I have a simple question. Is there any possibility to store math operator in variable? I have a code like that:

```
public ICollectionView FilteredCollection
            {
                get
                {
                    return filteredCollection;
                }
                set
                {
                    filteredCollection = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("FilteredCollection");
                }
            }



 FilteredCollection.Filter = x => (
                    (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DynamicSearchEmployeeName) || ((Employee)x).EmployeeName.Contains(DynamicSearchEmployeeName))
                    && (DynamicSearchEmployeeID == null || ((Employee)x).EmployeeID == DynamicSearchEmployeeID)
                    && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary) || ((Employee)x).EmployeeSalary == Convert.ToInt32(DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary))
                    && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DynamicSearchEmployeeDesigner) || ((Employee)x).EmployeeName.Contains(DynamicSearchEmployeeDesigner))
                    && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DynamicSearchEmployeeEmailID) || ((Employee)x).EmployeeName.Contains(DynamicSearchEmployeeEmailID))
                    );
```

What I want to achieve:
In fourth line (DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary) math operator should be depended on following conditions:

```
if (IsPressedEqual == true)
VARIABLE = "=="
if (IsPressedLess == true)
VARIABLE = "<"
if (IsPressedGreater == true)
VARIABLE = ">"
if (IsPressedLess == true && IsPressedEqual == true)
VARIABLE = "<="
if (IsPressedGreater == true && IsPressedEqual == true)
VARIABLE = ">="
```

Scenario:

For example I put a value like 10000 in textbox, then click on button with "=" operator. As a result I want to receive Employees with Salary equals than 10000.
Then I click on ">". And I have Employees with Salary greater and equals 10000.

[image]

```
 FilteredCollection.Filter = x => (
                        (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DynamicSearchEmployeeName) || ((Employee)x).EmployeeName.Contains(DynamicSearchEmployeeName))
                        && (DynamicSearchEmployeeID == null || ((Employee)x).EmployeeID == DynamicSearchEmployeeID)
                        && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary) || ((Employee)x).EmployeeSalary VARIABLE Convert.ToInt32(DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary))
                        && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DynamicSearchEmployeeDesigner) || ((Employee)x).EmployeeName.Contains(DynamicSearchEmployeeDesigner))
                        && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DynamicSearchEmployeeEmailID) || ((Employee)x).EmployeeName.Contains(DynamicSearchEmployeeEmailID))
```

Comment: How did you intend to use that on the query? What is `FilteredCollection`?

Comment: can you show the bit where the operator would be *used* in the ideal scenario? You can't store an operator *in isolation*, but: you can *compose* queries - for both LINQ-to-Objects (`IEnumerable<T>`) and LINQ-to-(whatever) (`IQueryable<T>`) - and you can build expression trees very flexibly (by using an alternative construction syntax to the typical compiler-interpreted construction). So: how would you *use* it? this *hugely* impacts any answers

Comment: i don't think you store the variables tehmself , but you can store the [Func<>()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Indeed... seconding what Patrick asked... where will these queries run? Locally as Linq2Objects or will they be translated by something like Linq2EF/Linq2Sql?

Comment: I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a simple Rule Based Engine ... I think it will help you in your issue ...

please find it as a nuget package here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/IbnSherien.RuleBasedEngine/

you can create a rule like this:

```
var rule = RuleEngine.CreateRule<Employee>()
                     .If<Employee>(e => e.EmployeeSalary).GreaterThan(DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary)
                     .Validate();

FilteredCollection.Filter = x => (
                    (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DynamicSearchEmployeeName) || ((Employee)x).EmployeeName.Contains(DynamicSearchEmployeeName))
                    && (DynamicSearchEmployeeID == null || ((Employee)x).EmployeeID == DynamicSearchEmployeeID)
                    && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary) || rule.Match((Employee)x).IsMatch)
                    && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DynamicSearchEmployeeDesigner) || ((Employee)x).EmployeeName.Contains(DynamicSearchEmployeeDesigner))
                    && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DynamicSearchEmployeeEmailID) || ((Employee)x).EmployeeName.Contains(DynamicSearchEmployeeEmailID))
```

feel free to add any comments or contribute to the package